# How to use variable in python 3 logger filename?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Hi I want my python script to print minute wise log so I want variable **b** to be replaced but its not happening and log file generating with name  **%(b)s_python.log**

Please Help !

```
import logging, datetime

a=datetime.date.today()

b=a.strftime("%y_%B_%a_%H%M")

print(b)

logging.basicConfig(filename="D:\%(b)s_python.log",level=logging.DEBUG,format="%(levelname)s %(asctime)s-%(message)s")

logging.debug("Hi Sudhirrrrrrrrr")
```

Comment: You will need a special logging handler for that. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) about logging handlers for details.

Comment: you'll need to specify the %b in the format section and not the filename.

Comment: Did you try `filename="D:\{0}_python.log".format(b),level=logging.DEBUG,format="{0} {1}-{2}".format(levelname, asctime, message)`?

Answer (score 1):

datetime.date.today() does not give you the current hour and minute.

```
import logging, datetime
a=datetime.datetime.now()
b='D:\\'+a.strftime("%y_%B_%a_%H%M")+'s_python.log'
print(b)
logging.basicConfig(filename=b,level=logging.DEBUG,format="%(levelname)s %(asctime)s-%(message)s")
logging.debug("Hi Sudhirrrrrrrrr")
```